# Как сделать вывод метода? Запуталась

Tags: java

Никак не соображу как сделать вывод. Вроде все также, как в первом методе. Но все равно ошибка. Искала в инете информацию, но все равно не могу сообразить(

```
public class Solution {
    public static int min(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        int m2;
        if (a < b)
           m2 = a;
        else 
           m2 = b;

        int m3;
        if (m2 < c)
          m3 = m2;
        else
          m3 = c;

        int m4;
        if (m3 < d)
          m4 = m3;
        else
          m4 = d;

        return m4; 
       //напишите тут ваш код
    }

    public static int min(int a, int b) { // тут ошибка
      if(a<b)
        return a;
      else if(b<a)
        return b;
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(min(-20, -10));
        System.out.println(min(-20, -10, -30, -40));
        System.out.println(min(-20, -10, -30, 40));
   }
}
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке нужно включить в вопрос. Еще лучше предварительно его вбить в поиск.

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: Без ошибки сложно что-о сказать

Comment: Ошибка, вероятно, заключается в том, что обработаны не все события. А что делать программе, если a=b?

Answer (score 3):

У вас метод `int min(int a, int b` не всегда возвращает значение, на что и ругается компилятор. А именно вы никак не обрабатываете ветку `else` в условии

```
if(b<a)
  return b;
```

Точнее, эта ветка у вас и вовсе отсутствует. Либо напишите `else return <что-нибудь`>, 
либо добавьте в конце метода недостающий `return`

Comment: На данный момент единственный ответ, который объясняет что не так и предлагает минимальное исправление

Comment: Спасибо. Поняла. Но программа все равно ничего не выдает, хоть ошибок и не показывает

Answer (score 2):

лучше таки наверное типа так:

```
public static int min(int... args) {
    int minValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i:args) {
        if(i < minValue)
           minValue=i;
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
public static int min(int... numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("нет чисел для сравнения");

    int min = numbers[0];
    for (int number : numbers)
        min = Math.min(min, number);

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Мой вариант таки правильнее :)

Comment: @Barmaley да, согласен, ваш вариант вполне ок

Comment: @Barmaley только если вызвать метод без аргументов, он вернет MAX_VALUE что не является минимальным элементом ;)

Comment: Соль то как раз в этом :) - это лучше чем выкидывать ексепшн

Comment: @Barmaley а вот это кстати довольно спорно.

Comment: Это слишком умно для меня 0_о

Comment: @Валентина поверьте здесь нет ничего сложного, это базовые возможности языка, и чем раньше вы начнете ими пользоваться тем лучше.

Comment: Именно этим уже 5 дней и занимаюсь. Надеюсь, понимание придет вовремя, а не во время экзамена))

Answer (score 1):

Замените метод `min(int a, int b)` на следующий:

```
public static int min(int a, int b) { 
   if (a < b) {
         return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

или даже так, ещё проще:

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
        return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

И в этом случае метод вернёт меньшее из двух чисел (или `b`, если они равны - а если два числа равны, то всё равно ведь, какое из них возвращать).

Comment: ? a : b как это расшифровать? Учу программу меньше недели)

Comment: @Валентина, это тернарный оператор; `x ? a : b` в случае, если условие `x` выполняется, то выполняется  `a`, иначе  `b`